My new wireless router does not have connectivity after install
My previous wireless router (Asus RT-AC88U) died (WAN port no longer gets internet traffic from cable modem). Purchased new wireless router Asus GT-AX11000 Pro and set it up: New router does not receive traffic from cable modem either. New router SSID is displayed on wireless devices (phones) with "no internet access" exclamation mark.
Previous setup:
Netgear Nighthawk CM1150V Cable Modem for Xfinity internet and voice. IP: 192.168.100.1
Asus AC3100 RT-AC88U wireless router. IP:192.168.1.1, subnet mask 255.255.255.0
All ethernet connections (2 laptop/ docking stations) and wireless devices (10 various devices) were recognized and connected with no issues.
Current setup:
Netgear Nighthawk CM1150V Cable Modem for Xfinity internet and voice. IP: 192.168.100.1
Asus ROG Rapture GT-AX11000 Pro. IP: 192.168.1.1, subnet mask 255.255.255.0
No connectivity from cable modem to router (2.5 gbps WAN port w/ brand new cat6 cable).
No connectivity from wireless devices - SSID is visible and can connect to net work "no internet access".
Worth mentioning that plugging an ethernet cable from cable modem to laptop NIC = 100% connectivity with internet access.
I'm not understanding the lack of connectivity when the IP addressing did not change.
Sure would like to know what I'm missing here...
Thanks!

Have you turned off your cable modem, left it off for a minute or two, and then powered it back on? This is a pretty normal part, in my experience, of switching downstream devices for a cable modem. Also, do you own the cable modem, or do you lease it from your ISP?

Yep - performed cable power cycle: unplugged, left off for 2 min, re-plugged in to power. I own the cable modem - do not lease it.

The cable modem is not in bridged mode and there are 4 ethernet (LAN) ports available on my cable modem; I have the router plugged into port #1 (same as previous router). All cables have been replaced too.

Update: Had to (hard) factory reset both Netgear Cable modem and Asus router and have Xfinity re-activate services on it, put basic security on router and it talks to the cable modem. I have internet traffic and a WAN IP. Have reconfigured router with heavy security, changed IP address form default and completed 2 firmware updates.       All is well with the world once again.
